# How to Invert everything On Page except images

Tags: javascript, html

I was thinking of a simpler way to change the colors on a page without having to write additional CSS for dark mode. After searching I came across the use of jQuery in very which sort of works to an extent but inverts the images on the page too. In my case, it would be better not to have images inverted but texts only. How do I achieve this? I have tried

```js
$("#ibutton").click(function() {   $("body:not(img)").css("filter", "invert(2)") })
$("#ibutton2").click(function() {   $("body").css("filter", "invert(0)") })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png" width="128px"> 
 <br><font color="red">I am Logo</font>
 <br>
  <input id="ibutton" value="invert" type="button"/>  <input id="ibutton2" value="revert" type="button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong because you are selecting body. You have to select all elements in the body except images You can do like below

```js
$("#ibutton").click(function() {   $("body").find("*:not(img)").css("filter", "invert(2)") })
$("#ibutton2").click(function() {   $("body").find("*").css("filter", "invert(0)") })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png" width="128px"> 
 <br><font color="red">I am Logo</font>
 <br>
  <input id="ibutton" value="invert" type="button"/>  <input id="ibutton2" value="revert" type="button"/>
```

There is another way of doing invert color by not adding inline style to all the elements by only add one class to body and style the class like below

```js
$("#ibutton").click(function() {   $("body").addClass('invert') })
$("#ibutton2").click(function() {   $("body").removeClass('invert') })
```

```css
body.invert *:not(img) {
  filter: invert(2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png" width="128px"> 
 <br><font color="red">I am Logo</font>
 <br>
  <input id="ibutton" value="invert" type="button"/>  <input id="ibutton2" value="revert" type="button"/>
```

Comment: Notice that this sets the inline style of all the elements on the page, excluding img elements.

Comment: @StevenHelson if my answer is helpful for you. You can accept my answer by pressing tick button left side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

$("#ibutton").click(function() {   **$("body *").not("img")**.css("filter", "invert(2)") })
$("#ibutton2").click(function() {   **$("body *")**.css("filter", "invert(0)") })

```js
$("#ibutton").click(function() {   $("body *").not("img").css("filter", "invert(2)") })
$("#ibutton2").click(function() {   $("body *").css("filter", "invert(0)") })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png" width="128px"> 
 <br><font color="red">I am Logo</font>
 <br>
  <input id="ibutton" value="invert" type="button"/>  <input id="ibutton2" value="revert" type="button"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).